# How can I get this assert_raise assertion to pass?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mocha.js, minitest

I have created a custom Exception that I want to be raised when I reach Amazon SES's max send rate for its SimpleEmailService. Nothing about the API needs to be known but here is the code that tries to execute what is happening:

test file:

```
  mailer_test.rb

  it 'should not resend an email when ses limit has been reached' do
    assert_raise Reverificaton::Process::SesMaxSendLimit do
      Reverification::Process.expects(:ses_limit_reached?).returns(true)
    end
    AWS::SimpleEmailService.any_instance.expects(:send_email).never
    Reverification::Mailer.resend_soft_bounced_notifications
  end
```

Here is my code file:

```
process.rb

module Reverification

  class Process

    class SesMaxSendLimit < Exception; end

    class << self

      def send_email
        raise SesMaxSendLimit if ses_limit_reached?
      end

    end
  end
end
```

The error I receive is that the exception is not raised

```
Reverification::Process::SesMaxSendLimit expected but nothing was raised.
```

Why would the exception not be raised? I've mocked the `ses_limit_reached?` to return `true` and I'm sure I have the scope correct. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have the code that's going to trigger that exception **inside** the `assert_raise` block. I'm assuming that's the two statements you have after the block, so instead of what you have, (I think) you should have this:

```
it 'should not resend an email when ses limit has been reached' do
  assert_raise Reverificaton::Process::SesMaxSendLimit do
    Reverification::Process.expects(:ses_limit_reached?).returns(true)
    AWS::SimpleEmailService.any_instance.expects(:send_email).never
    Reverification::Mailer.resend_soft_bounced_notifications
  end
end
```